# How to check API calls in testflight build with charles proxy tool?

Tags: ios, api, testflight, charles-proxy

I need to check the api call in test flight build and using the charles proxy tool, Any idea how can we do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you be more specific? What did you try? what is the problem you are facing? did you try https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-iOS/Setting-Up-Charles-to-Proxy-an-iOS-Device/ta-p/15285

Comment: In addition, the app you want to check may have ssl pinning. In that case you might get through it having original certificate and private key it's using to be 'man-in-the-middle'. Though if you have access to the code, it's easier to disable ssl pinning for test builds